# C program crashes when calculation performed

Tags: c

I have this program where I calculate employee bonus based on their salary. Program terminates when n ===999. But my problem is when I calculate the bonus,in either case "Debug 1" or "Debug 2" gets printed.
and program crashes without any errors.

This is my first program in C. I am familiar with java and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. I am using Code::blocks for programming in C.

Could someone kindly point out the error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    float basic;
    float bonus;

    for(;;)
    {
        printf("Enter the Emp No = ");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        if(n==999)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Enter Employee Salary\n");
            scanf("%f",&basic);
            printf("Basic Salary is %f",basic);

            if(basic < 100000)
            {
                printf("Debug 1");
                bonus = 0.75 * basic;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Debug 2");
                bonus = 0.5 * basic;
            }
            printf("Employee %s Bonus is %.2f",n,bonus);
        }

        basic = 0.0f;
        bonus = 0.0f;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last `printf` statement prints `n` as `%s` (string).  `n` is an integer and should not be printed as a string.

```
printf("Employee %s Bonus is %.2f",n,bonus);
```

should be:

```
printf("Employee %d Bonus is %.2f",n,bonus);
```